# Feature importance in regression model

Tags: machine-learning, regression, random-forest, xgboost, feature-extraction

I am working on a regression problem.
I fitted several algorithms including random forest and XGboost.
Both of them have ways that can show you the feature importance.
However, when I display the features in order, I get a slightly difference order of importance between the two.
Should I assume the more accurate model has the most accurate features in order of importance?

Comment: That may not always be true, but that's the best way to go ahead.

Comment: I'm by vbharfav875. But don't forget that it is about the importance of the regressors in the model and not about causality. That's could be because the correlation between the regressors